# How to minimize process crush with FUSE file system

Tags: fuse

I do work on FUSElib base file system, and process might periodically stop or hang because of internal bugs or exceptional situation. It's critical for disc intensive read/write sotware to use disc mounted with fuse implementation. Any stop/restart might lead to date lose, even if I put fuse process running under supervisor. Any technics exists to minimize this?

Comment: The question is too general. You have to figure out what causes the crashes. You may start by mounting fuse with the `debug` option (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.fuse.8.html) and read messages in _stdout_ to analyze the crash

Comment: @OrenKishon I don't agree question is general. if you do software development for more than year you know ANY process can shut down unexpectedly if it running for a weeks of months, for files system this could crush fully your db instance, even 1ms delay not good.

Comment: I wasn't saying your question wasn't in place. I am just saying you should give more specific details about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @OrenKishon let me try to be more specific, I was thinking of option to run fuse backend as several processes (or maybe threads) to do not rely on one process be alive 100% time

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Refuse-to-crash-with-Re-FUSE-Sundararaman-Visampalli/022fc284362d04569a1561c3d04dfe0f377d6112

Answer (score 0):

The fuse backend architecture is a process running an event loop that on each request (open, read, etc) starts a worker thread to handle it. That is not something available for you to change using the fuse API.
The only way for you to handle crashes and hangs is to have an outside watchdog monitor program to remount your fs whenever it crashes or hangs. Inside your fuse fs implementation you should insert a recovery module that once in a while stores the fs state to disk and also knows to import it back when remounted.

Update: 
Adding link to a system doing just that, as referred by comment above (thanks man!)
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Refuse-to-crash-with-Re-FUSE-Sundararaman-Visampalli/022fc284362d04569a1561c3d04dfe0f377d6112